# trying to connect to mongodb Atlas using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am working on a small project(REST API) using nodeJs + MongoDB. I have been able to install MongoDB locally and connect to it using mongoose. However for some reason, when I try to connect using MongoDB Atlas it fails. It looks like it connects but then after 2 seconds, I get an error message saying sockets closed(see error below). I have no clue what is going on. I have whitelisted my IP, checked my login info to make sure I am using the correct password and indeed I am using because I am able to connect using MongoDB compass. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 My current local ENV package versions are:
    nodeJs:V9.7.1
    mongoose:V6.1

=== MongoDb Atlas ===
    mongodb:3.6
```

Below is the code that I am using to connect to the database:

```
var express = require('express'),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
user = require('./api/models/userModel'), 
config = require('./api/config');
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var authRoutes = require('./api/routes/authRoutes'),
userRoutes = require('./api/routes/userRoutes'),
reviewRoutes = require('./api/routes/reviewRoutes');

const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:myPass@cluster0-shard-00-00 zd6jq.mongodb.net/myDb');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Swagger Info
var options = {
    explorer : true
};

app.use('/swagger', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument, options));
//END Swagger Info

//REGISTER ROUTES
userRoutes(app);
authRoutes(app);
reviewRoutes(app);

app.listen(port);

console.log('iReview RESTful API server listenning on port: ' + port);


module.exports = app;
```

====ERROR MESSAGE ===

```
    /Users/mdiez/node_test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: server cluster0-shard-00-00-zd6jq.mongodb.net:27017 sockets closed
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/mdiez/node_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:325:47)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:219:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/mdiez/node_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:101:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:219:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mdiez/node_test/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:142:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:219:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:127:13)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:558:12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var uri = 'mongodb://<usernamr>:<password>@<clustername>/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=<replica setname>&authSource=admin';

var db = mongoose.connect(uri).catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

Specify the replica set name, ssl true and authentication database. This is based on reference from Atlas documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to connect to Compass and Application. You just need to the following:

1. replace all the three primary and secondary shard from Cluster -> Overview
2. replace natours-app with your cluster name.

**Compass:**
mongodb://babar_bahadur:PASSWORD@natours-app-shard-00-00-ybksz.mongodb.net:27017,natours-app-shard-00-01-ybksz.mongodb.net:27017,natours-app-shard-00-02-ybksz.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=natours-app1-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&retryWrites=true&ssl=true

**Application:** 
mongodb://babar_bahadur:PASSWORD@natours-app-shard-00-00-ybksz.mongodb.net:27017,natours-app-shard-00-01-ybksz.mongodb.net:27017,natours-app-shard-00-02-ybksz.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=natours-app-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true